# Statistics on Game Center Achievements

Tags: ios, game-center

Is there a way to gather/download/view statistics on my iOS app's achievements for all of my users?

- For example, is there a way I could see the percent of my app's users that have completed each achievement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using Game Center. You could certainly use another system of tracking this.